# How do I select and click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, user-interface

```
<div id="subNav-Requests" class="suit-sub-nav" style="">
  <ul class="page-container">
    <li>
    <a class="navLink0" href="/MyApp/reporting/list/data.do">
        <span>Report Data</span>
    </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I have a code like this. I am trying to simulate a click on `'Report Data'`. What I am trying is

```
var nav = 'div#subNav-' + mainNavId; //results in 'div#subNav-Requests'
$(nav+' a.navLink0').trigger('click');
```

No errors, nothing happens. I also tried this

```
$('a.navLink0').trigger('click');
```

to the same effect. I have to select the `subNav-Requests` because there are many more like that, for E.g. `subNav-Reports`, `subNav-Allergies` etc. with the same structure but with many `navLinks` inside.

Comment: Did you try `$('a.navLink0')[0].click()`?

Comment: What is the triggering of the click trying to do exactly? Navigate away or calling an attached event?

Answer (score 3):

Calling click on an element just executes any event handlers attached to the element.  It will not send the browser to the href of an a tag.  To do that the best I can think of is:

```
var href = $('a.navLink0').attr('href');
window.location.href = href;
```

Does that meet your need?

Answer (score 1):

please try `$('a.navLink0', nav).click();`

Comment: It is better to use find()

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know you cant simulate an actual click on the link, what you are doing is simply triggering a click event, but that isnt enough.

You could set a listener for the event by

```
$('a.navLink0').click(function() {
    window.location = $(this).attr("href");
});
```

and then triggering the click event, but why are you doing this? wouldnt a redirect fit your purpose better?

```
window.location = $('a.navLink0').attr("href");
```